# How to use UpdateItem to change Number values

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In my database I have an item (`type: 'TOTAL'`) that tells me how many items of a particular type (`type: 'CONFIG'`) exist. When I remove a `CONFIG` item, I want to decrease the number stored in `TOTAL`. `TOTAL` doesn't necessarily exist yet, so I want to set it to 0 if it doesn't exist, or subtract 1 from its current value if it does.

```
if total exists
  total = total - 1
else 
  new total = 0
```

I'm using UpdateItem because I don't have any info about the `TOTAL` item before running this query. If I use ADD and `TOTAL` doesn't exist yet, it will set the value to 0 and then subtract 1, instead of just setting it to 0 like I want. I've tried to use SET with if_not_exists instead, but it won't take an operand in the case that the item does exist, which is when I want it to subtract 1.

Here's my current query, which gets run when I call the function to remove a `CONFIG` item:

```
aws dynamodb update-item \
  --table-name application \
  --key '{"type":{"S":"TOTAL"},"id":{"S":"CONFIG"}}' \
  --update-expression "SET TotalConfigs = if_not_exists(TotalConfigs-1,:z)" \
  --expression-attribute-values '{":z":{"N":"0"}}'
```

The error I get is

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation:
Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: "-", near: "TotalConfigs-1"
```

I'm not surprised by this as I understand it won't work. Is there a way to do what I want without using multiple queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the pattern of OPs question, this is quite doable with a single query:

```
aws dynamodb update-item \
    --table-name 'application' \
    --key '{"type":{"S":"TOTAL"},"id":{"S":"CONFIG"}}' \
    --update-expression "SET TotalConfigs = if_not_exists(TotalConfigs, :one) - :incr" \
    --expression-attribute-values '{":one":{"N":"1"}, ":incr":{"N":"1"}}'
```

This will initiate the TotalConfigs at 0 (or 1 - 1) and subsequent updates with the same query will decrease TotalConfigs by 1.

Answer (score 1):

Safest and most efficient approach is to use [transactions](https://medium.com/signiant-engineering/using-dynamodb-transactions-to-model-relational-data-c13619ca58ae). You will have a transaction with two operations, one will be a PUT with the new item and the other an UPDATE using [Atomic Counters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters) for the `total`